# Extracting file path from a string

Tags: c, string

I have a string which looks like:

```
HTTPS DOWNLOAD_FILE /ab/cd/e/f/kk.png\r\n\r\n
```

Here `\r\n\r\n` denotes the end of request marker. I need to extract the file path which is `/ab/cd/e/f/kk.png`. How could I do this?

I tried breaking the string by space (using the function `strtok`) and then looping down to get the third token but is there a better to do this?

Comment: "is there a better way". Maybe. But using `strtok` is a reasonable way to do it. So unless you have a more specific problem this question isn't that suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `char *p = strchr (str, '/');` will return a pointer to your first `'/'`. Then just `p[strcspn (p, "\r\n")] = 0;` to *nul-terminate* after `'g'` in `"png"`. Then `p` will point to your path. (note: the string must not be a *String-Literal*, if it is make a copy first)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin As I try to print this using `printf("%s",p)`, it gives out segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: I added an example in my answer. Drop a comment below if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, to parse the path from your string, your string must be mutable and not a *string-literal*, then it is just a matter of locating the first `'/'` marking the beginning of your path, and then removing the *request marker* with `strcspn`.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    char str[] = "HTTPS DOWNLOAD_FILE /ab/cd/e/f/kk.png\r\n\r\n",
        *p = str;

    if ((p = strchr (p, '/'))) {        /* locate '/' in str, validate */
        p[strcspn (p, "\r\n")] = 0;     /* terminate at 1st CR */
        printf ("path: %s\n", p);       /* output resulting path */
    }
}
```

The `strcspn` function returns the number of character in the string beginning at `p` that are NOT character in the *reject* set of characters `"\r\n"`. (you could just use `"\r"` there). So the return is the number of character between the first `'/'` in your path and the last `'g'` in `"...png"` (i.e. the *string-length* of your wanted path). When you then do `p[len] = 0;` you are nul-terminating the string after `len` characters. Where you use `strcspn (p, "\n\r")` to get the `len`.

Think of it this way, the equivalent would be:

```
    if ((p = strchr (p, '/'))) {            /* locate '/' in str, validate */
        size_t len = strcspn (p, "\r\n");   /* get length up to 1st CR */
        p[len] = 0;                         /* terminate at 1st CR */
        printf ("path: %s\n", p);           /* output resulting path */
    }
```

We just combined the two into a single expression. Also note to nul-terminate a string at any point, you are just setting that character to the nul-character `'\0'` which is numerically equivalent to `0`. See [ASCII Table & Description](http://asciitable.com).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/pathfromstr
path: /ab/cd/e/f/kk.png
```

Comment: Could you please explain the call to `strcspn` and assigning `0` in the same call. Documentation at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html was not clear to me.

Comment: I am receiving `str` using the `recv` method (from sockets). I receive it in a char array declared as `char buffer[200]`. Will this method still work? Because you mentioned that the string must be mutable.

Comment: Yes, `char buffer[200]` is a simple mutable character array of 200 characters. Now since you are receiving the input via sockets (using a low-level `read` most likely), there is a chance that you are not getting an entire string on each read (you may not get any at all on one iteration, and then get more than your string on the next). How are you reading from the socket?

Comment: I am using the `recv` method available with sockets. It looks like `recv(socket_fd, headers, sizeof(headers)-1, 0);` Here `headers` is declared as `char headers[200]`. `headers` would contain the string i.e. `HTTPS DOWNLOAD_FILE /ab/cd/e/f/kk.png\r\n\r\n`

Comment: My concern is that `headers` is not *nul-terminated* to begin with. Try calling `bzero (header, 200);` immediately before the `recv` call to ensure your `headers` buffer is zeroed. That way you can treat `headers` as a string. If there was no `'\0'` at the end of `HTTPS DOWNLOAD_FILE /ab/cd/e/f/kk.png\r\n\r\n` -- that would explain your SEGFAULT.